# binary video video source not working in chrome based browsers,but in others. 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu ,Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, php, video

i searched and tried many ways to get my video player working in chrome browsers.
even with a empty cache i get errors;
they worked until i switched video source to binary data. works fine in mozilla both in windows and in linux, without any errors, but not in others. I load this page within an iframe on my homepage.
video source comes from  `$_[GET]` method and then attached to a data-src attribute.

`/*plus other functions*/`

`video=player.querySelectorAll(".play-window")[0].getElementsByTagName("video")[0];`

`function is_playing(curTime){`
`return feedback;`
`};`

`function can_play(what){`
`if((!what.canplay||!what.canplaythrough)&&what.loaded==false&&what.src==''){`
`what.setAttribute('poster',src_err);total.innerHTML='src Error';`
`}else{is_playing(what.currentTime);`
``` };`` ``` };

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){`
`video.src=src_arg_all[0].getAttribute('data-src');video.load();can_play(video);`
`});`
`/*plus other functions & event listeners*/`

so far i've tested this problem on windows and linux based browsers.
nothing special.
if more details needed i will post them here. thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: i'v found a solution that worked.'if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('chrome')){video.src=src_arg_all[0].getAttribute('data-src');};'

Answer (score 0):

```
`if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('chrome')){video.src=src_arg_all[0].getAttribute('data-src');};`
```

it was so easy it must have slipped my mind. ;-)